# Creative way to say "It was a coincidence."?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there any creative phrase that could substitute the sentence "It was a coincidence."?

Comment: Why is that not asking ELU to do your homework for you, please?

Comment: If you simply copy someone else's words - it isn't creative. It has to come from yourself as creator.

Answer (score 4):

**Happenstance**

> Coincidence.
>       "it was just happenstance that I happened to be there"

<sup>Source: [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&q=Dictionary#dobs=happenstance)</sup>

See [here](http://grammarist.com/usage/happenstance/) for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If the coincidence has a positive outcome, you could say it was a [**happy accident**, TFD gives the following definition:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+happy+accident)

> A mistake or unplanned event that results in a beneficial outcome or pleasant surprise.

If the coincidence has a negative outcome, you could say it was a [**mishap**, OLD gives the following definition:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mishap)

> bad luck, or an unlucky event or accident

A more neutral noun is [**turn of events**, which CD defines as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-of-events)

> a change in a situation

This can be altered to suit your specific context, as CD illustrates in their example:

> an *unexpected/strange/dramatic* turn of events

The adjectives in italic can be changed to fit the situation at hand.